# how to disable resizing an IE window by double click on title bar or dragging through edges

Tags: html

I need to disable resizing an IE window by double click on title bar or dragging through edges. Is there any way to detect the double click event on title bar or to stop dragging the window through edges?

Answer (score 2):

The `onresize` event is not cancelable. So no, you can't do this.

My "useful suggestion" is to consider why in the world you would want to do this, and what possible reason is there that a user might accept having a window size forced upon them.

Comment: The reason to stop the resizing is as follows, I build an audio player through elements, and i have setted the player to a fix size, but the click event on title bar is not in my control, i need to disable the resizing coz the seeking functionality is working when window is of fixed size, but it gets wiered when resized, now is there any solution to do that.

Comment: Sounds like you need a `<div style="position:relative;">...</div>` container.

Comment: @user1000557 Then you should work on fixing your seeking functionality instead of searching for ways to limit the functionality of someone else's computer.

Answer (score 1):

Simply isn't possible.  Security model wouldn't allow such a thing, nor should it.

Comment: Sorry there wasn't a more useful answer.